# Erro no insert no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Bem estou desenvolvendo um inventário de TI além de dar alguns erro , ao inserir um hd de 80 ele só salva o zero e os outros dados não são inseridos tambem. como posso resolver isso . 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o código

```
<form method="post" action="cadastrando.php" onSubmit="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sistema de Inventário</legend><br />

        <label class="borda">Setor: </label>
        <input class="form_inp" type="text" name="setor" size="30" required><br />

        <label class="borda">Usuário:</label>
        <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" size="30" required><br />

        <label class="borda">O/S :</label>
        <input class="form_inp" type="text" name="os" size="30" required><br /><br />

        <label class="borda">Hd : </label>
        <input  class="form_inp"type="text"  name="hd" size="30" required><br />                        
        <hr />          
        <label class="borda">Memória:</label>
        <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="" name="memoria" size="30" required><br />

        <label class="borda">Processador: </label>
        <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="processador"  name="processador" size="30" required><br /><br />
        <hr />
        <label class="borda">Cd/Dvd: </label>
        <select class="form_inp"  name="cd"> 
            <option value="Sim">Sim</option> 
            <option value="Não">Não</option> 
        </select>

        <br />

        <label class="borda">Placa Mãe: </label>
        <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="placam" name="placam" size="30" required><br />

        <label class="borda">HostName: </label>
        <input class="form_inp"type="text" id="host" name="host" size="30" required><br /><br />

        <label class="borda">Monitor/Patrimônio/Marca/Modelo: </label>
        <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="monitor" name="monitor" size="30" required><br />

        <label class="borda">Nobreak/Patrimônio/Marca/: </label>
        <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="nobreak" name="nobreak" size="30" required><br />

        <label class="borda">Placa de Rede : </label>
        <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="placar" name="placar" size="30" required><br />

        <label class="borda">Placa de Vídeo: </label>
        <input class="form_inp" type="text" id="placav" name="placav" size="30" required><br />

        <hr />
        <input type="submit" style="float: right;" value="Cadastrar" >
        <input type="reset" style="float: right;" value="Limpar">

    </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    print_r($_POST);
    $setor=$_POST['setor'];
    $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
    $hd=$_POST['hd'];
    $memoria=$_POST['memoria'];
    $processador=$_POST['processador'];
    $cd=$_POST['cd'];
    $placam=$_POST['placam'];
    $host=$_POST['host'];
    $monitor=$_POST['monitor'];
    $nobreak=$_POST['nobreak'];
    $placar=$_POST['placar'];
    $placav=$_POST['placav'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO setor(setor,usuario,hd,memoria,processador,cd,placam,host,monitor,nobreak,placar,placav) VALUES('$setor','$usuario','$hd','$memoria','$processador','$cd','$placam','$host','$monitor','$nobreak','$nobreak','$placav')";
    $resultado_cadastro = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
}

    ?>
```

E outro erro que dar é o seguinte , por que tá dando esse erro se tá tudo certo , ficarei grato.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pela action do teu form, a parte php deve estar dentro do ficheiro `cadastrando.php`.

Os erros depois, se estou a pensar bem, consegues resolver com uma simples verificação do metodo http que foi usado para fazer a requisição dentro do ficheiro `cadastrando.php`:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $setor=$_POST['setor'];
    $usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
    $hd=$_POST['hd'];
    $memoria=$_POST['memoria'];
    $processador=$_POST['processador'];
    $cd=$_POST['cd'];
    $placam=$_POST['placam'];
    $host=$_POST['host'];
    $monitor=$_POST['monitor'];
    $nobreak=$_POST['nobreak'];
    $placar=$_POST['placar'];
    $placav=$_POST['placav'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO setor(setor,usuario,hd,memoria,processador,cd,placam,host,monitor,nobreak,placar,placav) VALUES('$setor','$usuario','$hd','$memoria','$processador','$cd','$placam','$host','$monitor','$nobreak','$nobreak','$placav')";
    $resultado_cadastro = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
}
?>
```

Para testar isto podes colocar dentro deste if acima o seguinte:

```
...
print_r($_POST);
...
```

E depois vês se imprime os dados que preencheste no formulário, depois sabes que podes fazer o que tens a fazer com eles.

Mas, lembra-te que tens de declarar a tua conecção que está na variável `$link` antes da inserção efetiva na BD, pelo que vejo não estás a declara-la/importa-la em lado nenhum

Nota que podes deixar o teu php no mesmo ficheiro do formulário, mas tens de apagar '`action="cadastrando.php"`' dentro do `<form ...`, e usa o mesmo pedaço de código que coloquei acima

Comment: Os erro saíram mais não tá fazendo fazendo o insert dos dados . atualizei o código a cima .

Comment: Não mudei e já confirmei sua resposta

Comment: Deves colocar outra pergunta com tudo o que for relevante à tua connecção e maneira que estás a inserir os dados, escusas de colocar o HTML. Eu vou tentar ajudar @allanaraujo , aqui já não faz sentido nem consigo perceber o porquê, de não estar a inserir. Dá algum erro? Estás com a variável `$link` ok?

Comment: farei isso . e colocarei todo código

Comment: @allanaraujo, o html não precisas, se já estás a receber os dados, faz esse teste que te digo em cima para testar isso. Mas se vires os dados que preencheste no form não coloques o html que não é preciso

Comment: já coloquei  a pergunta.